# Fireplace - Pilot stays on, fire goes off

Tags: gas, fireplace, thermocouple

Trying to figure what is wrong with my gas fireplace. I tried to start it few days ago first time since last winter, I brushed the thermocouple, thermopile and the burner, also used compressed air spray. Now the issue is that the pilot (blue/yellowish color) stays on, fire starts properly and after 10-15 seconds it dies completely (I can hear a click and even pilot goes off). Any ideas what is wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: What brand / model is your system, since the pilot stays lit their may be a dirty fire eye that can’t see the burner flame and shuts down as a secondary safety.

Comment: Hi Ed, thank you for the reply, I have a Napoleon CDVS600. Could you please elaborate about the dirty fire eye ?

Comment: I wanted to make sure on the type of season you have some use an “eye” that senses the flame others used a probe in the flame.  Usually if the thermopile style fail the gas is shut off , on the eye style it thinks the main burner has not ignited and shuts that off this is why I mentioned the eye because your pilot is staying lit.